# How to find Local IPs

Tags: ip

Is there a way to find local IPs for devices on your network? I have tried the following in a command line:

1. Ipconfig
2. ping 10.51....
3. arp -a

Is this correct and if not what is?

Comment: *Is it* correct? SO is not meant to replace a web search engine, where you can write the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows
ipconfig

For linux
ifconfig ,
ip addr

in linux you will find ip of eth0 and lo(look up that is for self-connection)